# Catching multiple errors in one try/catch

Tags: powershell, try-catch, file-permissions

So trying to do a simple `try`/`catch` updating the share access for a folder on a server in PowerShell.

```
try {
    Grant-SmbShareAccess -Name [FolderName] -AccountName [GroupToShare] -AccessRight Read -Force
    Grant-SmbShareAccess -Name [FolderName] -AccountName [GroupToShare] -AccessRight Read -Force
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error Granting one or more permission: $_" -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta
}
```

Is it possible to catch the specific grant access statement and print the group name it failed on.

Say I had the two groups:

- NA\admin
- NA\dev

and that the the `Grant-SmbShareAccess` failed for both groups, could I catch and print out:

```
Permission Failed for: NA\admin
Permission Failed for: NA\dev
```

using only one try catch?

Comment: Inside your catch, you can use `$PSItem.InvocationInfo.Line` to get the command that caused the exception. If your group is stored in a variable, you can use the variable in the catch block.

Comment: in addition to what AdminOfThings said, you likely should consider why "best practice" is to have the try wrapped around the narrowest source of errors. that would mean you would have a `try/catch` wrapped around _each_ of those lines so that you can handle any error _specifically_. [*grin*]

Comment: okay that makes sense, for some reason I blanked and didn't think of looping over and doing the try except individually..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop over the arguments:

```
foreach($group in 'NA\admin','NA\dev'){
  try {
    Grant-SmbShareAccess -Name [FolderName] -AccountName $group -AccessRight Read -Force
  }
  catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to grant permission to: $group"
  }
}
```

Comment: Shoot didn't even thinking about a loop...thank you so much that is perfect.